# Avoid form resubmission in Play Framework 2.0

Tags: javascript, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have a basic POST form being submitted. Every time a form is submitted, a database is updated. 
If someone tries to refresh the page, you get a "Confirm form resubmission?". Is there anyway to avoid this?
I know this is achievable with PHP but thats not an option here

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The action that accepts your form POST should commit the data to the database and then redirect to another action. That way, when the user hits refresh, they will only be reading data, not writing it.

Here's an example:

```
  public Result terminate(Long depositKey) throws Exception {
    depositsService.cancelScheduledDeposit(getCurrentUser().memberKey(), depositKey);
    return redirect(routes.ControllerFactory.deposits.terminateConfirmation(depositKey));
  }
```

Comment: @Omar: Glad it worked out for you. Would you mind accepting my answer by clicking the check mark? I'm in this game for the reputation, not to help people ;P Hahaha just kidding but seriously I'll take a green tick please :D

Comment: Done ;)
Haha tell me about it. I still have a student badge. 
Thanks again!
I have another question, but I will post it in a separate page
Cheers